# AWS CDK Running `cdk synth` for Another Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When use AWS CDK to provision resources in an VPC, it requires me to specify AWS account and region through `env` environment variables.
I have CLI access to my dev account, but no access to prod account.
I would like to use `cdk synth` to generate cloudformation template for production account. To do that, I specifies the account ID in `.env` file.
But `cdk synth` command returns me following error.

```
[Error at /whitespace-app-fargate/whitespace-app-fargate/FargateStack] Could not assume role in target account using current credentials (which are for account xxxxxxxx) User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:user/myqinjie is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::yyyyyyyyy:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-yyyyyyyy-ap-southeast-1 . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
```

Is there a ways to run `cdk synth` to generate cloudformation template without validation?

Comment: Came across the same constraint after over a year. Were you able to find a way to run `cdk synth` without all those validations?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run cdk synth against an account that you do not have access to.

You need use a role or user that has sufficient permissions to execute cdk synth against production account.

May I ask what is your usecase?

If you want to validate which resources will be created, you can run against your own account but use production stage and production region.
The only thing different when effectively deploying to production will be the account.

Comment: Thank you, Lucasz. Due to security, no CLI is allowed in Prod env. I use dev environment to generate CloudFormation template file, and use it on Prod env. It works fine for serverless resources so far. 
Currently I need to use it to deploy Fargate clusters in a VPC. I tried to specify AWS account, VPC ARN etc in `.env` file. But it throws above error. 
One way is for me to generate CloudFormation template against DEV environmnent, then I manually replace account ID, VPC ARN etc. But it is too troublesome.

Comment: I am wondering whether CDK CLI can be run without validation against AWS account in above case.

Comment: it is impossible to validate if you do not specify an account.  You should let your CI/CD process deploy your resources.
Usually if you synth with dev it should not be alot more different as with prod right?

Comment: How do you usually deploy to production?

Comment: You can also use cross account deployments but then you still need to deploy resources in production to make sure you are able to validate production. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cdk-credential-plugin/

Comment: I have no access to PROD through CLI. I can only login through AWS Console through VPN.
I deploy to production using cloudformation templates generated from CDK projects. The projects usually contains a CDK Pipelines so that it will auto rebuild pipeline and redeploy when there is an update in codecommit repository.

Comment: Why dont you ask your system admin or devops engineer to deploy the cdk pipeline so you dont have to care about this?

Comment: We had similar constraints here, but settled on granting devs accounts "trust for lookup" to some production accounts. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-customizing for documentation. Basically, this creates a role that can be assumed from devs account, which allows for read only access to almost every aspects of the infrastructure...

Comment: I support this setup @jwatkins. We have a seperate account in AWS only for Authentication. Then we use roles to get read/write access to our production account, staging account and dev account.

Comment: Will replacing account and region in generated cloudformation from `cdk synth` work for that account and region?